# how to store Select Statemnt data to var in scala play2.6 slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have written One SQL select query and i want to store the result returned from this query to some Variable how to do that

```
    val  count=(sql"""SELECT count(User_ID)  from user_details_table where email=$email or Mobile_no=$Mobile_no""".as[(String)]     )
   val a1=Await.result(dbConfig.run(count), 1000 seconds)

    Ok(Json.toJson(a1.toString()))
```

here i am not able to find out the id that is returning from this query

this is my complete code what i am trying to do

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, ControllerComponents}
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, ControllerComponents}

import scala.concurrent.Await
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.mvc._
import com.google.gson.{FieldNamingPolicy, Gson, GsonBuilder}
import play.api.libs.json.Json

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import javax.inject.Inject
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import play.api.libs.json.{JsPath, Writes}
import slick.jdbc.GetResult

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
//import play.api.mvc._

import org.joda.time.{DateTime, Period}
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.mvc._


import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import com.google.gson.Gson
class adduserrs @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc)
{



  def adduser(Name:String,Mobile_no:String,email:String,userpassword:String,usertype:String) = Action
  {
    import play.api.libs.json.{JsPath, JsValue, Json, Writes}

    val gson: Gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).create
    val dbConfig = Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/equineapp?user=root&password=123456", driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")


    var usertypeid=0;

    if(usertype=="Owner")
    {
      usertypeid=1;
    }
    else  if(usertype=="Practitioner")
    {
      usertypeid=2;
    }


    val  count=(sql"""SELECT count(User_ID)  from user_details_table where email=$email or Mobile_no=$Mobile_no""".as[(String)]     )
    val a1=Await.result(dbConfig.run(count), 1000 seconds)

    Ok(Json.toJson(a1.toString()))
    if (count==0) {

      val setup1 = sql"call addusersreg ($Name,$Mobile_no,$email,$userpassword,$usertypeid);".as[(String, String, String, String, Int)]
      val res = Await.result(dbConfig.run(setup1), 1000 seconds)
      Ok(Json.toJson(1))
    }
    else {
      Ok(Json.toJson(0))

    }
  }
```

from above code iam just trying to insert userdetails in database
if user exists in db then it will return response as 0 or else it will return response as 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here you are only counting, so perhaps you just need a variable of type `Long`:

```
SQL("select count(*) from User where tel = {telephoneNumber}")
   .on('telephobeNumber -> numberThatYouPassedToTheMethod).executeQuery()
   .as(SqlParser.scalar[Long].single)
```

You just totally changed the question, anyway, for the error you mentioned in the comment, the reason is that you have no connection as well as you did not define the database you want to use (`default` or otherwise). All the database calls are within the following block:

```
db.withConnection{
  implicit connection => 
     //SQL queries live here. 
}
```

Moreover you need to `db` is injected if it is not the `default` database:

```
class myTestModel @Inject()(@NamedDatabase("nonDefaultDB") db: Database){???}
```

**Follow MVC Architecture**: For consistency with model-view-controller architecture, all your database calls should be within `models` classes. The controller method needs to call the models method for the result.

Comment: i have edit my post and added whole code the solution which you have provided throwing me an exception "could not find implicit value for parameter connection: java.sql.Connection"

Comment: @Abhinay updated the answer. You need to inject the db and working with that, within the method, that deals with the db.

Comment: thanks i got solution for my above problem .i have one more query "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52367079/image-upload-to-blob-container-in-azure-using-scala-play2-6"  can you please help me